# How to display multiple table data into one layout

Tags: android, sql

I have 2 tables, Logs and Price. Content from table logs is displayed into textviews for each item. Now I would like to display some content form table Price into the same base adapter.

Is it possible and how should I done that?

This is my activity with base adapter in which i displayed content form table logs. How should I display here content form table Price?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_logs_listview);
        boolean sort = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("sort", false);
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewItem);

        final String place = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("keyPlace");
        dbHandler = new LogsDBHandler(this);
        ArrayList<Logs> logsList = sort ? dbHandler.getAllLogsByPlace() : dbHandler.getAllLogs(place);

        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.LogMassResult);
        double sum = 0.0;
        for( int i=0; i<logsList.size(); i++) {
            sum += logsList.get(i).getResult();
        }
        result.setText(String.format("%.2f", sum));

        listAdapter = new LogsArrayAdapter(logsList);
        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    private class LogsArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<Logs> logsList;
        private List<Price> priceList;

        public LogsArrayAdapter(List<Logs> logsList) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DisplayLogs.this);
            this.logsList = logsList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return logsList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return logsList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return logsList.get(position).getId();
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_display_logs, parent, false);
            }
            Logs log = logsList.get(position);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textPlace)).setText(log.getPlace());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textNumber)).setText(log.getPlate_number());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textSort)).setText(log.getSort_id());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGrade)).setText(log.getGrade());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDiameter)).setText(log.getDiameter());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLength)).setText(log.getLength());
            Log.d("Value", log.getCreatedAt());
            try {
                Date dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(log.getCreatedAt());
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDate)).setText(new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").format(dt));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d("Masa Trupca", String.format("%.2f", log.getResult()));
            String final_result = String.format("%.2f", log.getResult());
                    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textAmount)).setText(final_result);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

and this is my dbQuery for getting price. I created this in my Logs class. Here I'm displaying price based on parameters in string.

```
public Cursor getPrice() {
        Cursor cursor = db.query("Price", new String[]{"price_stump_kn", "price_stump_eur", "road_price_kn", "road_price_eur"}, "sort = ? AND grade = ? AND length = ? BETWEEN diameter_dg = ? AND diameter_gg = ?",
                new String[]{getSort_id(), getGrade(), getLength(), getDiameter(), getDiameter()}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Price price = new Price();
                price.setStumpPrice_kn(cursor.getString(0));
                price.setStumpPrice_eur(cursor.getString(1));
                price.setRoadPrice_kn(cursor.getString(2));
                price.setRoadPrice_eur(cursor.getString(3));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

So how should I display content from two tables inside one base adapter (listview)?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the records in those two tables are related. Your remark that you included a DB query in the `Logs` class (which I suppose is a domain class, not a DAO), I suspect that your class structure is somewhat confusing. Therefore, I try to sketch a class structure for each of the two ways of mixing your logs and prices.

Solution A: Each log is connected to a price, and data of both are to be displayed in one item.

```
class LogDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
...
   public Log getLogs(some selection parameters) {
      Get logs according to selection parameters, and for each log
         call getPrice(selection parameter according to log just found)
         log.setPrice(price just found)
   ...
```

Now, in your adapter, the items are Logs, and with `log.getPrice()` you can get the price attributes and are free to mix log and price attributes in your adapter to display them in your view item.

Solution B: There is a mixed list -- some items are logs, others are prices

The key to this is that you can dynamically decide, for each item, which layout to use in your adapter. So the structure will be:

```
class LogPriceDAO extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
...
   public Object getLogsAndPrices(some selection parameters)
      Get logs and prices in some sequence, according to your business
      logic and the selection parameters (If logs and prices have some
      common superclass, use that instead of Object)
...

class LogsAndPricesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
   @Override
   public View getView (int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
      ...
      Object currObject = this.getItem(i); // or common superclass
      ...
      View v;
   if (currObject instanceOf Log) {
      v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.log_layout, null)
      now fill fields of your log layout
      ...
   } else {
      if (currObject instanceOf Price) {
         v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.price_layout, null)
         now fill fields of your price layout
         ...
   return v
```

The `instanceOf` operator is considered bad style by some people. So the immaculate way is to define a common superclass for `Log` and `Price` that offers an operation `public Boolean isLog()` from which the caller can decide which type of object it got.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll keep that in mind. 
I was mistaken and not need this at all. I figured out that I have problem with my sql query(for me very complex) and can't make it work.